# Is there any language model that is able to generate text given both beginning and ending sequences?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

Generative language models like GPT-2 can generate text given beginning sequences, and [cloze Transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.08561) can fill in the one-word blank between two sequence. Is there any generative language model that can generate multi-word text that connects given beginning and ending sequences as an extension to both models like GPT-2 and cloze transformer?

Input:

```
Beginning sequence: What is Love?
Ending sequence: Love is an emotional state, not a physical one.
```

Output:

```
[What is Love?] Love is a state of mind, a feeling, 
an emotion, or a mental state. It is the feeling 
of being in love with someone or something. The 
word "love" is derived from the Latin word for 
"to love," "lēgēre," which means to feel, to be 
attracted to, and to love. [Love is an emotional 
state, not a physical one.]
```